# How to show convergence in a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose that $\{x_n\}→x$ where $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in a normed space V and $x ∈ V$. Show that $\forall y ∈ V, \{x_n + y\} → x + y$.

Comment: I think you should include the term "vector" somewhere in your post, because a metric space doesn't have to be a vector space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of convergence in a metric space:  A sequence $\{x_n\}$ is said to converge to $x$ if $\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N\implies d(x,x_n)<\epsilon$.  For a normed vector space, $d(x,x_n)=|x-x_n|$

The result then follows from the definition and the fact that $|(x+y)-(x_n+y)|=|x-x_n|$

Comment: Editted: Ah-hah, thank you!

Comment: That was nicely done.

Comment: This is why knowing the basic inequalities of analysis-like Cauchy-Schwatz and the Triangle Inequality-is so important.

Comment: Although this particular analysis problem did not need the triangle inequality, most of them do :)